# Android GridView wrap_content cell width and dynamic number of items per row

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview

In Android, how do I create two GridView(s) (or the supposedly better RecyclerViews) to create something that looks like this...

[image: mockup]

...where the number of items/cells per row will vary depending on the text length and both views should not be able to scroll independently (ie. the rootview would probably be a ScrollView and it will provide the ability to scroll).

I've tried GridView for the most part but I can't make the cell width wrap_content property to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. I did a bit of a ghetto solution where I used RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager and a max of 8 possible items/grid per row and calculate the length the text would occupy with respect to it's font family and font size, and then determine whether it would take 1,2...8 grid(s) to occupy their length. It doesn't really look 100% similar to the sample picture I gave above, but it doesn't look half as bad. The two RecyclerViews are both nested inside a NestedScrollingView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tag view for android using that you can create view as you want.
see below library for more information

- https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView